# Java - Could not set field value [null, permissions=[]}]

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a class User, that have a Role, role have a list of permission (enum), when i try to get a User by ID i get an error! In my database the data is OK, i have an user with a rol created.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity= com.ecommerce.model.Role.class)
    private Role role;
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "rol")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RoleType role;
    @Column(name = "permisos")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Permission.class)
    private List<Permission> permissions;
```

```
public enum RoleType {
    manager,
    seller,
    buyer
}
```

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not set field value [null, permissions=[]}] value by reflection : [class com.ecommerce.model.User.role] setter of com.ecommerce.model.User.role; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [null, permissions=[]}] value by reflection : [class com.ecommerce.model.User.role] setter of com.ecommerce.model.User.role
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set field value [null, permissions=[]}] value by reflection : [class com.ecommerce.model.User.role] setter of com.ecommerce.model.User.role; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [null, permissions=[]}] value by reflection : [class com.ecommerce.model.User.role] setter of com.ecommerce.model.User.role
```

Answer (score 0):

this solves the problem **spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).